# Convert a list of images to grayscale using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I have a pickled training dataset containing 32x32 RGB images. As a preprocessing step, I want to convert them to grayscale. 
I read in the training dataset as -

```
import pickle
import cv2

training_file = "../data/train.p"

with open(training_file, mode='rb') as f:
    train = pickle.load(f)

X_train, y_train = train['features'], train['labels']
```

Then, I try using a `for` loop to convert each of the images to grayscale using the following code -

```
for i in range(0,len(X_train)-1): 
    X_train[i] = cv2.cvtColor(X_train[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

But this throws the following error -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a920a94faefc> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(0,len(X_train)-1):
----> 2     X_train[i] = cv2.cvtColor(X_train[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (32,32) into shape (32,32,3)
```

However, if I repeat this procedure using just a single image, I don't get any error. I did the following - 
[image: convert single image to grayscale]

Can someone explain the reason for the error and how I could convert the entire list to grayscale?

Comment: From the error message, it seems that your images in `X_train` do not have 3 color channels. Are you sure they are not already grayscale images ? Can you show how you create the pickled training data ?

Comment: I've verified that the training images are all (32, 32, 3), using the `shape` property. You can see the screenshot of running `img.shape` at - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HlagXozCosqICIQ1MRGnDLQTvUGVy-Gl/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that you're trying to store grayscale images with shape `(32, 32)` in an array that stores RGB images with shapes `(32, 32, 3)`.

```py
X_train_grayscale = np.zeros(X_train.shape[:-1])
for i in range(X_train.shape[0]): 
    X_train_grayscale[i] = cv2.cvtColor(X_train[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

This creates a new array called `X_train_grayscale` that will contain your grayscale images after converting.

(Of course you need the usual `import numpy as np` at the top of your Python script to make it work.)